# Refresh Controller in Pulled state for the first time when Segment Controller Index changes?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol, uirefreshcontrol

I have refresh-Controller on TableViewController . At ViewDidLoad i am allocating the refresh controller .

Problem Scenario :

When view is loaded and i change the segment-controller . The refresh controller is pulled .

After that it works as it should.

For any doubts please comment on the same . Thanks

Comment: you mean when view load you want to show refresh controller or when segment change ?

Comment: I don't want refresh controller to be in pulled state until and unless user drags the table view down .

Comment: can not understand exactly what you want.

Comment: I have segment controller over table view . When i first come to the view and change the selected segment index . the refresh controller comes without pulling the table . that should not happen . And its happening only for the first time .

Comment: did you set tableview contentoffset in viewDidLoad? otherwise it wont show.

Comment: Nopes . I haven't set contentOffset.